# How to trigger an image hover effect when hold mouse over another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I dont have any idea how to make it work

Css:

```
    .name
{
    width: 270px;
    height: 77px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 600px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s;
}

.name:hover
{
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.photo
{
    width: 270px;
    height: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 77px;
    left: 600px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s;
}

.photo:hover,
{
    top: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

I want when i hold the mouse over the .name which is an image to activate the .photo hover effect and vice versa, any idea?

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: I tried alot of scripts but no one worked

Comment: You will need to use Javascript to do this. Since you tagged jQuery, look into `hover()` here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ If you've tried a lot of scripts, you should include one here and we can tell you why it didn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: Are `.name` and `.photo` elements next to each other? You can use the `+` or `~` adjacency selectors to match them.

Comment: Well i thought that this $(".name").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass(".photo:hover"); 
 }); will work but then i realised that photo:hover it is not a class ...

Comment: Please post the HTML you plan on using.

Comment: I tried both + and ~ it didnt worked <span class="title"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/MortandoGF" class="title">Games Fanatics</a></span></span>

<span class="moveMe"><img src="WORK/new/new/games extend0001.png" width="240" height="400" /></span>

<img src="WORK/Name of game/CRYSIS 3.jpg" width="270" height="77" class="name" />

<img src="Images/page0_pic1.jpg" width="270" height="310" class="photo" />

<script>

</script> ... and the script its empty as i deleted what didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

```
/* What you want the thing being hovered over to look like */
.name:hover {
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: top 0.3s;
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* What you want the thing being hovered over to look like */
.name:hover ~ * {
    /* Some styles */
}
```

In order for this to work, the items that you want to style need to be siblings of the `.name` element being hovered over. The `~` is a css sibling selector.

Comment: This is generally the approach I'd take to avoid having to rely on JavaScript.  Note that you can use ~ (general following sibling) instead of + (adjacent following sibling) for less specificity.  Note that this won't work for previous siblings however, so this only answers 1/2 of the original question (it's missing the "vice-versa").

Comment: Thats the reason why i cant use this :(

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class like

```
.photo:hover, .photo.hover {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Then toggle class `hover` on the `photo` element.

This woul be a javascript solution, not just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**JS**

```
$('.name').hover(function () {
    $('.photo').addClass('hover');
}, function () {
    $('.photo').removeClass('hover');
});

$('.photo').hover(function () {
    $('.name').addClass('hover');
}, function () {
    $('.name').removeClass('hover');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.name:hover, .name.hover 
.photo:hover, .photo.hover
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/S3D4L/1/)

Comment: you need add class `hover` instead of `photo.hover`

Comment: i just did that too and the photos are moving separately

Comment: yes i tried first as you said and it didnt worked then i tried with photo.hover instead of hover...i dont understand what im doing wrong :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/f3bcA/3/ here your working code. you forgot add jquery

Comment: so here is the part of my html with css and javascript http://jsfiddle.net/mortando/f3bcA/9/ it still doesnt work, just take another look maybe i put something in the wrong way as im new at this :/

Comment: in jsfiddle "Frameworks & Extensions" (dropdown left top) choose jquery 1.9.1

Comment: just add in to your head this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This is generally the right approach with JS, since you can't trigger :hover states programmatically.  Here's a working version without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/franksvalli/HR5U9/1/

Comment: i updated in jsfiddle with photos so you can see http://jsfiddle.net/mortando/f3bcA/14/ drag the scroll bar to the right